# SQL Server INSERT statement is not executing but I am not receiving an exception either

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

On my button click event I want to insert a row into a table. When I click the button, I get no exception and I also don't get my messagebox to show either. I have the messagebox as a way to check to see if the query had been executed.

When I step through it skips the MessageBox and doesn't throw an exception.

```
private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

    var select = "INSERT INTO Trinity3(Date, Device_S_N, Student_Last_Name, Student_First_Name, Student_Number, School, Grade, Damage)" +
                 "VALUES (@Date, @Serial, @LastName, @FirstName, @StudentNum, @School, @Grade, @Damage)" +
                 "COMMIT";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CPS1113020004; Initial Catalog=Coweta Public Schools; Integrated Security=True");               

    // Create a SqlCommand instance
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select, connection);

    // Add the parameter
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = select;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", theDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial",txtSerial.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",txtLastName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",txtFirstName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentNum", txtStudentNum.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School",txtSchool.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", txtGrade.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Damage", txtDamage.Text);

    // Execute the query
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted successfully");
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle exception, show message to user...
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    this.Visible = false;

    var searchForm = new SearchForm();
    searchForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Put `[Date]` in brackets.  Your "date" should be a date, and not a string.  Don't think you need that COMMIT line.

Comment: Clean the solution and make sure you are in debug mode.  Then build and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: An empty `Catch` block can never report a problem.  Also, `AddWithValue` is a bad idea

Comment: How does it "skip the message box"?  If that line of code is executed then a message box would be displayed.  Are you sure you've fully re-built the code since your last changes?  Or that your (empty) `catch` block isn't being reached?

Comment: You have nothing in catch section, exceptions are probably being ignored silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing an exception but you are not seeing because there is nothing in your catch block.

1. Look up Try with Resources convention and always use it. This will automatically close your connection for you even if there is an exception.This is a must.
2. Add an exception to your catch block so you can see the error.
3. Your SQL string needs to have spaces after each section. When you are concatenating with "+" no extra space is created. So your query actually looks like this:
   `INSERT INTO Trinity3(Date, Device_S_N, Student_Last_Name, Student_First_Name, Student_Number, School, Grade, Damage)VALUES (@Date, @Serial, @LastName, @FirstName, @StudentNum, @School, @Grade, @Damage)COMMIT`
4. Instead of writing your query in the application, you should create a stored procedure in the database that will contain all of the logic necessary to get the data. Then your application will simply call a one word stored proc instead of having a giant string representing your t-sql. ALSO you can actually test your stored proc and make sure it works without the application being involved.